# selenium firefox driver python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have python functional scripts using selenium 2.32 with the Firefox driver. On a html like below:

```html
<div id="reminder">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <strong>text i need</strong>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to do a css selector search with `"#reminders div ul li strong"`. I get the `WebElement` (say assigned to variable element) for that, but when i try to get the text (using `element.text`) i get empty.

Also this is a very consistent behavior when i debug my test, where as when i run the whole suite sometimes it is successful and sometimes it fails, I am not able to find out what the problem is please let me know if anyone has ideas of how to proceed.

Also i am running this on python 2.7

Comment: Is it just the text which gives problems? For example if you try and do `getElement()` to find the parent, does it correctly return the `<li>` element or does that fail too?

Comment: @vincebowdren i can get the parent element with element.parent. the problem is only getting the text within the <strong> tag.

Comment: @user1177636 We use jquery for the frontend javascript and i have used the selector from firebug to make sure that there is only one element.

Comment: If this is a consistent behaviour when you debug, there must be some mismatch between what your script is expecting and the actual browser DOM. Can you use [pdb](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) to debug the script, and find out what the source of the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

I am just going to put a brief of what i found out and what i did to solve my problem. And will pose a few questions at the end of the explanation of the behavior i am observing. First to put the pseudo html below

```
<div id="reminder">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <strong>text i need</strong>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The django template we have will translate to above with out any javascript. We use accordian on top of the above using

```
$('#reiminders').accordian({   alwaysOpen: false, active: false,collapsible: true,autoHeight:false})
```

which translates the above html to roughly

```
<div id="reminder">
  <div class="a few accordian specifc classes" >
    <ul>
      <li>
        <strong>text i need</strong>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

now looks like the click bind function on the accordian is mapped to the inner div with the accordian class on it and not the   so when in my script i was doing a css_selector with "#reminder" and calling click() on it it was not opening the accordian and hence the inner  text was not being displayed because of which my "#reminders div ul li strong" selector with text was giving empty text (I still dont understand why it was empty the whole element might have been hidden but still the text was not empty), Once i changed my click css_selector to use something like '#reminders div' and call click() on it, things started working. I was able to consistently get the tests passing while debugging.

Now For the questions:

- I still dont understand why the tests pass when run as part of the suite in CI sometimes and fail sometimes while fail always when run under debug mode on my IDE
- I have a few tests(7-10) that always fail when run as part of the CI, while when i rum them locally individually they pass, I also ran the tests in the same fashion they run on CI and i get lesser number of failures but still some(1-2), though when i run those failing tests individually they pass.There can be various problems with tests dependency which might cause this but on local same tests pass. I will put out the results once i sort this out.

thanks for the answers.